# Decode nested JSON array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, nested, decode

I have a nested JSON array which I want to decode. I have already found a way to decode a specified info in the object but it's not working so good.

This is the code I used to decode (name, cover and street) from the JSON object:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
    JSONObject events = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = events.getString("name");
    JSONObject cover = events.getJSONObject("cover");
    String imgurl = cover.getString("source");
    JSONObject place = events.getJSONObject("place");
    JSONObject loc = place.getJSONObject("location");
    String street = loc.getString("street");

    ItemListView item = new ItemListView(name,street,imgurl);
    listItems.add(item);
    adapter = new ItemListAdapter(listItems, getActivity());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I want to decode more info like description, end_time and start_time.

The JSON data structure looks like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "description": "",
         "end_time": "",
         "name": "",
         "place": {
            "name": "",
            "location": {
               "city": "",
               "country": "",
               "latitude": 0000000,
               "longitude": 000000,
               "street": ""
            },
            "id": ""
         },
         "start_time": "",
         "id": ""
      },
      {
         "description": "",
         "end_time": "",
         "name": "",
         "place": {
            "name": "",
            "location": {
               "city": "",
               "country": "",
               "latitude": 0000000,
               "longitude": 000000,
               "street": ""
            },
            "id": ""
         },
         "start_time": "",
         "id": ""
      }
    ]
}
```

I put the decoded info in a ListView in my Android app and that is why I have an adapter and ListView in the code.

Any help is greatly appreciated :) 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple you can get other string like this -:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject events = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String description= events.getString("description");
                String end_time= events.getString("end_time");
                String start_time= events.getString("start_time");

            }
```

Comment: Omg , i made it so complicated for myself, Thank you so much :D